# how can I improve my code to find increasing and decreasing sequences

Tags: python, sequence

I'm trying to write a function that would find the longest run of monotonically increasing or decreasing numbers. I've looked at many examples but none seems to fit this requirement: If L = [10, 4, 3, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 2] then the longest run of monotonically increasing numbers in L is [3, 4, 5, 7, 7] and the longest run of monotonically decreasing numbers in L is [10, 4, 3]. The function should return the value 26 because the longest run of monotonically increasing integers is longer than the longest run of monotonically decreasing numbers. I've written a function that solves the problem but it's a brute force approach. I think there's a better approach but I'm not able to come up with one at this time.

This is what I've done to find all the sequences:

```
def longest_run(L):
    count_up = []
    count_down = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
       if (L[i+1] >= L[i]) and (L[i+1] != L[-1]):
           if L[i] <= L[i-1]:
               count_down.append(L[i]):
               count_down.append('=md') # sequence separator
               count_up.append(L[i])                              
            else:
                count_up.append(L[i])
                continue
       if L[i+1] == L[-1]:
           if L[-1] < L[i]:
               count_down.append(L[i])
               count_down.append(L[-1])
               count_up.append(L[i])
           elif L[-1] > L[i]: # if last value is greater than value in L[i]
               count_down.append(L[i])
               count_up.append(L[i])
               count_up.append(L[-1])
           break
       elif L[i+1] < L[i]:
           if L[i] > L[i-1] and i > 0: # needs at least 2 values to compare
               count_up.append(L[i])
               count_up.append('=mi')
               count_down.append(L[i]) # higher value - start new sequence
           elif L[i] <= L[i-1]:
               count_down.append(L[i])
           elif L[i] > L[i+1]:
               count_down.append(L[i])
return count_down, count_up
```

L = [10, 4, 3, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 2]

Comment: What is you intended formula to derive the value ```26``` from the two lists that your function creates?

Comment: No... the value 26 is a simple sum of the longest sequence and I can do that. I wanted to find a better approach than the brute force I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
L = [10, 4, 3, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 2]

count_up = [[L[0]]]
count_down = [[L[0]]]

# building monotonically increasing and decreasing runs
# we spit the original list into sublists of increasing o decreasing numbers.
for i in L[1:]:
    if i >= count_up[-1][-1]:
        count_up[-1].append(i)
    else:
        count_up.append([i])
    if i <= count_down[-1][-1]:
        count_down[-1].append(i)
    else:
        count_down.append([i])

# searching the longest
longest_run = max(count_up + count_down, key=len)
```

`longest_run` is `[3, 4, 5, 7, 7]`